Instructional TV series on common-world things
Several months ago I was watching in TV (NatGeo Latinoamerica I think but it could be Discovery Channel Latinoamerica or History Channel Latinoamerica) an advertisement about a new TV serie-documentary about "How to use several things from the common world in the correct way". 
I think remember that the translation in spanish was something like "¿Cómo se usa?" (How do to use?), and I tried several hours searching in youtube and google about spanish and english version, and in the nat geo or discovery webs but without any result (I think the problem is that the name is very common to search).
Sorry I don't have more information, because I just only saw a commercial. But the serie is really new (2013/2014)

Maybe NatGeo's Going Deep from this year? Here's the press release:

TYING YOUR SHOES.
MAKING ICE CUBES.
OPENING A DOOR.
ARE THESE SIMPLE DAILY TASKS? OR ARE THEY COMPLEX, INTRICATE MYSTERIES YOU’RE PROBABLY DOING WRONG?
NATIONAL GEOGRAPHIC CHANNEL INVITES VIEWERS ON A QUEST TO PERFECT EVERYDAY SKILLS IN GOING DEEP WITH DAVID REES.

Here's the bit about shoelaces:




Yes! it is!!! With this reference will be more easy for me searching in spanish. Thanks a lot!

"Hazlo bien" is the translation in spanish (Do it right). Tradduttore tradditore...

Cool! Glad you found it.
